# Multiple FadeIn/Out Sub-Menus with different designs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please find my detailed code here: https://jsfiddle.net/d8rduvjc/1/

I want to create a navigation with jQuery; therefore, I use the **FadeIn** and **FadeOut** command. For this I assigned a `<div>` as **FadeItem**.

Since there will be some sub-menus I will have multiple **FadeItems** in the navigation menu. Not all of them will have the exact same design because some of them will **FadeIn/Out** *below* the button whereas other once will **FadeIn/Out** *right next* to the button.

Therefore, I tried to divide the **FadeItems** into a **FadeItem_01** and **FadeItem_02**. However, now I have the issue that the **FadeItem_02** won't appear *right next* to the button anymore. Instead it appears *below* the button.

What do I have to change in my code so the **FadeItem_01** appears *below* the button and the **FadeItem_02** appears *right next* to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check is that what you want,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".button_desktop_01, .button_desktop_02").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem_01, .FadeItem_02").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.button_desktop_01 {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

 .button_desktop_02 {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.FadeItem_01 {
display: none
}

.FadeItem_01 .FadeItem_01 {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: 0;
width: 130px;
height: 100%;
}

.FadeItem_02 {
display: none
}

.FadeItem_02 {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 0;
width: 130px;
height: 100%;
}



ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation_desktop">

 <div class="button_desktop_01">1.0 Main Menu
  <div class="FadeItem_01">
   <ul>
    <li>1.1 Sub Menu </li>
    <li class="button_desktop_02">1.2 Sub Menu
     <div class="FadeItem_02">
      <ul>
       <li>1.2.1 Sub Menu</li>
       <li>1.2.2 Sub Menu</li>
      </ul> 
     </div>
    </li> 
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="button_desktop_01">2.0 Main Menu
  <div class="FadeItem_01">
   <ul>
    <li class="button_desktop_02">2.1 Sub Menu
     <div class="FadeItem_02">
      <ul>
       <li>2.1.1 Sub Menu</li>
       <li>2.1.2 Sub Menu</li>
       <li>2.1.3 Sub Menu</li>
      </ul> 
     </div>
    </li> 
    <li>2.2 Sub Menu </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div> 
 
 <div class="button_desktop_01">3.0 Main Menu
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Black Panther, that is exaclty what I want. Thank you but where was my mistake? I cannot see it.

Comment: If its working fine means please mark it answer correct, It will helpful to others in future.